# How to stack radio button group on top of each other using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20679/), right now it is display as

```
label1 a b c d e f
label2 a b c d e f
```

I want to change the position to

```
label1 a b c
       d e f
label2 a b c
       d e f
```

Originally I thought wrapping it around a div would work but it didn't.

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="k in test">
      <input type="radio" name="what" value="k" >
     <div style="display: inline-block;">
        label {{k}}
      </div>

      <!-- getting rid of this inline-block here will cause the first group not align in the same horizontal line -->
      <div ng-repeat="t in test2" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div>
        <div ng-repeat="n in t" style="display: inline-block;">
          <input type="radio" name="what2" value="n" >
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            {{n}}
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Did you take a look at ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat. Look under Special repeat start and end points. Can't figure it out here but i think it might be the way to go, just apply a <br /> at the end of the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so you need to set a width on your first ng-repeat div and then I added a class called "test" and grabbed the :nth-child(4) (this is the second set of radio buttons). JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/14wdtpem/
 The code is below:

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class="test" ng-repeat="k in test" style="width:200px">
      <input type="radio" name="what" value="k" >
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
        label {{k}}
      </div>

      <div  ng-repeat="t in test2" style="display: inline-block; ">
        <div >
        <div   ng-repeat="n in t" style="display: inline-block; ">
          <input   type="radio" name="what2" value="n" >
          <div  style="display: inline-block;">
            {{n}}
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test :nth-child(4){
  margin-left:65px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, creating one additional div wasn't enough -- I created an `inline-block` container for the lettered radio buttons, then a `block` container each for the new `firstRow` and `secondRow`. That way, the overall `rows` container could be displayed alongside each label.

Hope this helps!

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="k in test">
      <input type="radio" name="what" value="k">
      <div style="display: inline-block">
        label {{k}}
      </div>
      <div id="rows" style="display: inline-block">

        <div id="firstRow" style="display: block;">


          <div ng-repeat="t in test2[0]" style="display: inline-block;">
            <div>
              <div ng-repeat="n in t" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input type="radio" name="what2" value="n">
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                  {{n}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="secondRow" style="display: inline-block">


          <div ng-repeat="t in test2[1]" style="display: inline-block;">
            <div>
              <div ng-repeat="n in t" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input type="radio" name="what2" value="n">
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                  {{n}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnzeq7ce/).

Comment: Please post the corrected fiddle code in your answer as oppose to just linking to it on an offsite resource. This helps to better encapsulate the complete answer making it more useful for future visitors. It also prevents your answer from becoming obsolete and receiving subsequent downvotes if said offsite resource ever becomes unavailable.